# Echo php in a form input acting as a button with a path

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I created a shopping cart button and in my shopping cart page I have a total quantity count that I echo out. I want the echo'd value to be in my Shopping Cart button, but when I try to add in my echo to the value, it doesn't work. Is there another way to structure this to get my url image, value: Shopping Cart, and the echo'd quantity to show?

**My shopping Cart button:**

```
<form class="shopcart" id="block right" action="shoppingcart.php">
    <input type="submit" class="shopcart" name="shopcart" value="Shopping Cart <?php echo $totalquantity; ?> ">
</form>
```

**The total quantity count:**

```
<?php
        }

//Shopping Cart Quantity Count
if(isset($_SESSION['shopping_cart']) && is_array($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])) {
        $totalquantity = 0;
        foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] AS $product) {
            $totalquantity = $totalquantity + $product['quantity'];
        }
  }
  else {
       $totalquantity = 0;
  }
  echo $totalquantity;
?>
```

**CSS:**

```
/*----Add to cart Button-------*/

input.shopcart  {
background-image: url(images/cart24.png);
background-color: transparent;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 180px;
padding: 8px;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #7ac9b7;
background-color: #12BDB8;
color: #F0F8FF;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 15px;
cursor: pointer;
float: right;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px auto;
margin-top: -45px;
}
.shopcart:hover  {
    background-color: #10A8A3;
}
```

Is there a better approach to this to make this work? I have this shopping cart button on every page and want to make it so where ever the user is they will see the quantity of what is in their shopping cart.

Quick side question. I am unable to get my shopping cart image that is set to my url background out of the top left corner. No matter what I do with the background positioning it stays there. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong with it?

***Edited to show placement of total quantity variable

```
                    <form class="shopcart" id="block right" 

action="shoppingcart.php">
                        <input type="submit" class="shopcart" name="shopcart" value="Shopping Cart">
                    </form> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="whitepageOut">  
            <div class="whitepage">
                <div class="content">
                    <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>  
                <!-- Add in additional info. I made the above up, to test. Correct when ready! -->
                        <div class="floatright">
<?php           
            echo "<p>
            <a href='./shoppingcart.php?empty_cart=1'>Empty Cart</a>
            </p>";
?>
                        </div>
<?php
// Initialize cart
if(!isset($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['shopping_cart'] = array();
}
// Update Cart
if(isset($_POST['update_cart'])) {
    $quantities = $_POST['quantity'];
    foreach($quantities as $id => $quantity) {
        if(!isset($products[$id])) {
            $message = "Invalid product!";
            break;
        }
        $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$id]['quantity'] = $quantity;
    }
    if(!$message) {
        $message = "Cart updated!<br />";
    }
}

// Empty cart
if(isset($_GET['empty_cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['shopping_cart'] = array();
}
            if(empty($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])){
                echo "Your cart is empty<br />";
            }
            else {
        echo $message;
?>
                        <form action='./shoppingcart.php?view_cart=1' method='POST'>
                            <table class="carttable">
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="cartth">Name</th>
                                    <th class="cartth">Price</th>
                                    <th class="cartth">Category</th>
                                    <th class="cartth">Quantity</th>
                                </tr>
<?php                               
                        $base_price = 0;
                        foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $id => $product) {
                                    $product_id = $product['product_id'];
                                    $base_price += $products[$product_id]['price'] * $product['quantity'];
                                    $shipping_price += $products[$product_id]['shippingprice'] * $product['quantity'];
?>
                                <tr>
                                        <td class="carttd"><?php echo "<a href='./viewProduct.php?view_product=$id'>" . $product['name'];?><?php echo $products[$product_id]['name']; ?> </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="carttd"><?php echo '$' . $products[$product_id]['price']; ?></td> 
                                        <td class="carttd"><?php echo $products[$product_id]['category']; ?></td>
                                        <td class="carttd">
                                        <?php echo "<input type='text' name='quantity[$product_id]'  value='" . $product['quantity'] . "' />"; ?> </td>                                         
                                </tr>
<?php
                                }
                                //Calculates total
                                $total_price += $base_price + $shipping_price;
?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2"></td>
                                    <td class="tdcarttotal">Subtotal</td>
                                    <td class="tdcarttotal"><?php echo "$" .  $base_price; ?> </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2"></td>
                                    <td class="tdcarttotal">Tax</td>
                                    <td class="tdcarttotal">To be determined</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2"></td>
                                    <td class="tdcarttotal">Shipping Price</td>
                                    <td class="tdcarttotal"><?php echo "$" .  $shipping_price; ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2"></td>
                                    <td class="tdcarttotal">Total</td>
                                    <td class="tdcarttotal"><?php echo "$" .  $total_price; ?></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                                <input type='submit' id='button' name='update_cart' value='Update Cart'>
                        </form>
                <form action="checkout.php?checkout=1">
                    <input type="submit" class="checkoutbutton" value="Proceed to Checkout">
                </form><br><br><br><br><br>
<?php
            }
//Shopping Cart Quantity Count

        if(isset($_SESSION['shopping_cart']) && is_array($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])) {
        $totalquantity = 0;
        foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] AS $product) {
            $totalquantity = $totalquantity + $product['quantity'];
        }
  }
  else {
       $totalquantity = 0;
  }
  echo $totalquantity;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without showing more of the code, my guess would be that you are trying to show the button before the variable is actually assigned a value.

Edit:

Adding javascript to update the value of the submit button:

Change `<input type="submit" class="shopcart" name="shopcart" value="Shopping Cart">` to `<input type="submit" class="shopcart" name="shopcart" id="shopcart" value="Shopping Cart">`.

Add this at the end of your PHP code:

```
echo "<script>document.getElementById('shopcart').value = 'Shopping Cart $totalquantity';</script>";
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Correct. My shopping cart button is in my header. The variable is assigned at the bottom of the page after the quantity is configured.

Comment: You need to have the variable assigned before you try to call it. The code is processed in the order it appears in the file. One further solution would be to use javascript to set the value of the submit button after the variable is set.

Comment: Would I just move my variable to the top of the page then? How could I do this with JS. My goal is to have this work on every page. I added in more code to show the placement. See edit.

Comment: You could move the variable and the check to the top of the page (probably the best solution) or you can see my edits above to see how it could be accomplished via javascript.

Comment: Perfect! I used your JS approach to test it and it worked. If I created a file with my total quantity code in it and added it to every page with the require method. Do you think that would be the best approach to get this value on all pages?

Comment: Using a page that is required other than your footer or header page would be optional. Just to cut back on repeat code, it should only be on one place and included on every page that way you do not have to change it in more than one place if changes are necessary.